# Dragging an element causes input field to focus

Tags: jquery-ui, focus, draggable, blur

I currently have an element which contains both an input field and an overlay.
The overlay prevents the input field to get focus on dragging the parent.

HTML:

```
<div class="draggableObject ui-draggable"> // z-index 300
    <div class="objectContent">
        <input value="500"></input> // z-index 301
        <div class="overlay"></div>  // z-index 302
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(".overlay").on('click touchstart', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('input').focus();
});
$('draggableObject').on('drag', function(){
    $(this).find('input').blur();
});
```

If I drag the element and release the mousebutton, it causes the overlay to trigger the click event. How can I prevent this from happening?

I tried preventDefault() and stopPropagation(), but niether of these seem to work properly. Or I might've misplaced them.